# Embedding the set of all finite graphs in $\mathbb R^n$ so that more similar graphs are closer

Tags: graph-theory

Let $F$ be the set of all finite simple undirected graphs. Define $E(g)$ to be the number of edges in $g$. Define $S(g)$ as the set of all subgraphs of $g$. Define $g_1=g_2$ to mean that there exists a graph isomorphism between $g_1$ and $g_2$, and $g_1\neq g_2$ otherwise. Define $M:F\times F\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ by $M(g_1, g_2) = \max_{{h_1\in S(g_1)},{h_2\in S(g_2)},{h_1=h2}} E(h_1)$. ($M$ in some sense reflects the degree of similarity between two graphs, and similar questions arise where it is defined as, for example, the ratio between its current definition and the average of the sizes of the two graphs being compared.)

Does there exist an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that there exists a map $p:F\rightarrow R^n$ where for all $g_1,g_2\in F$ and $g_1\neq g_2$, $\Vert p(g_1)-p(g_2)\Vert = f(M(g_1, g_2))$ and $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$ is a strictly decreasing function over $\mathbb{N}$?

(I apologize if the notation is non-standard, it's been a long time since I studied graph theory. Edits/comments are encouraged.)

---

As originally stated, the answer is "no". Since unconnected graphs are included, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ it is possible to create an infinite set of graphs $G^*$ such that for all $g_1,g_2\in G^*$, $M(g_1, g_2) = k$. Simply take any graph with $k$ edges and add arbitrary numbers of unconnected vertexes. However, for every finite $n$, there can only be a finite set of points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which are all mutually at a given non-zero distance.

So I restate the question for the set of finite, simple, connected, undirected graphs.

Comment: Did you have a look at graph representation learning?

Comment: @VanBaffo Ah, thanks for the tip. I will start looking at the current results there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{n,k}$ be the path graph with $n$ vertices numbered $1,...,n$ where we add another vertex adjacent to the vertex $k$. Then for different $k_1,k_2\in\{2,...,\lfloor n/2\rfloor \}$ you still have $M(P_{n,k_1},P_{n,k_2})=n-1$.

Comment: Thanks, I have to admit I got stuck on the idea of trying to add stuff to large complete graphs instead of to simpler ones.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is still no. Your strategy will still work: it suffices to show that for every $A$ there exists a set of $A$ graphs all of which have the same mutual distance under the $M$ function. Take a path of length $2A$ and append a single edge to any of the first $A$ vertices. These $A$ graphs are all mutually non-isomorphic and have mutual distance $2A$ thanks to the common path.